# How can I conditionally display an error page in nginx?

Tags: nginx, webserver, http-status-codes, nginx-config

How can I configure nginx to return an error_page if the URI does not contain `ajax` but if it does contain `ajax` don't send an error page and just return the response? Something like the following but I can't figure out how to access $status. I want to do this for all statuses that are 4xx or 5xx

Essentially, I want to be able to receive a JSON response when there is an AJAX request error and an error page when the request failed to render HTML

```
# If the location contains ajax
location ~ ajax {
    # Return the error status code
    return $status;
}
# Location did not contain ajax so send an error page
error_page $status error.html;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I told you to show your full config. I'm not going to draw the required information from you bit by bit, so I'm going to delete my answer and giving this up. To solve this you'll need to check what are `proxy_intercept_errors on;`, `error_page`, `$upstream_status`, `$upstream_http_content_type`, however I'm leaving this to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was thinking about nginx directives wrong. I was thinking about it like a programming language as if the error_page for the non-ajax responses would be evaluated before the URIs containing ajax. Instead, the error_page directive defined in the location block for URIs that match the regex is what will be used. This ended up working perfect.

```
# All pages error page
error_page 404 400 401 402 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 500 501 502 503 504 505 error.html;

location ~ ajax {
    # Error page for URI containing ajax
    error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 error.html;
}
```